# Can I write a regular expression or regular grammar for this language?

Tags: regular-languages, regular-expressions

Let's say I have a formal language,

> a^n b^n which mean ab,aabb,aaabbb

Can I write any regular expression or grammar to create a language like this? I am positive not entirely sure that there is not regex possible, however have no idea about the grammar part?

Answer (score 3):

This language is context-free but not regular. It is isomorphic to the problem of matching open and closed parentheses: `(n)n` which is a well-known non-regular language. To prove this yourself, you would use the [pumping lemma for regular languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages).

Every regular grammar describes a regular language.
This language is not regular.
Therefore, there cannot be a regular grammar that describes it.